# Mousepad of laptop not working

Tags: 14.04, drivers, mousepad

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 version in Lenovo G505s laptop. My mouse pad not working since i installed Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding the following:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i8042.reset i8042.nomux i8042.nopnp i8042.noloop"
```

to

```
/etc/default/grub
```

and then execute this:

```
sudo update-grub
```

and reboot.

It worked on most cases as far as I know.

**OR**

If that doesn't help you can try to fill in a bug report using information at [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingTouchpadDetection).